# Linebreak inside Twitter Bootstrap label span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just find out that a linebreak inside the `<span>` tag can result in expected rendering in Twitter bootstrap labels.

See examples here:
http://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/aFuR3/1/

Is it a bug or something?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these document sections:

- [White Space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1)
- [White Space Processing Details](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space-processing)

As a general rule, you should avoid having whitespace immediately after an opening tag or immediately before a closing tag *inside of an element that contains text*.

```
<span>    bad  bad   bad</span>
<span>bad  bad   bad    </span>
<span>good    good  good</span>
```

This is because the agent behavior in those circumstances is not defined.

Whenever you encounter this kind of problem, the solution is simply to remove the offending whitespace and move on.